# Access Office 365 Discover Service with "app-only" token

Tags: office365

I am trying to query Office 365 Discovery Service REST API using "app-only" token obtained by following [client credential grant flow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) but it gives back Access denied. Is there a way to make this work?

```
{u'error': {u'message': u'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.', u'code': u'-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovery service does not support app-only token since Discovery’s goal is to provide the app with the endpoints for a given user. 
That said the error message provided here is not very useful, we will take the follow up to update it. 
Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if a service (deamon) apps can also discover office 365 APIs rest endpoints. The alternative is hard code URL in the code

Comment: why doesn't discovery api support app-only tokens? its the same thing - tell me what i can do and what the endpoints are. without it, we have to hardcode the urls, and we don't always know what the domain name is.

Comment: The Discovery Service only supports user centric scenarios, to get the endpoints for the current user. For deamon or appOnly scenarios we will be adding appOnly support to the Office 365 unified API, in which you don't need the Discovery Service because there is a single endpoint.

Comment: To use OneDrive for Business, I need to discover the tenant-specific root URL, also stated [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/sharepoint/release-notes.htm#api-end-point). Even if I use an app-only token, I still need to discover the URL in order to make the requests, the URL is otherwise not known. How am I supposed to find out the URL?

Comment: Discovering URLs is orthogonal to whether someone is using an app-only token or the usual user-specific access/refresh tokens. Even when using an app-only token I am making requests *on behalf of a given user*, and thus I need to discover the endpoints for that particular user. Whether I am using app token or not, this information is something contained in the request header and has nothing to do with the URL which the question is about

Comment: I recommend that you use Microsoft Graph to discover the URLs: To discover the OneDrive endpoint (aka SharePoint MySite):
Option 1: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/sharepoint/site?select=weburl, Option 2: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?select=mySite. To discover the SharePoint RootSite:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharePoint/site?select=weburl